# Running docker-compose on a docker gitlab-ci-multi-runner

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project running on Docker with docker-compose for dev environment.

I want to get it running on GitLabCI with a gitlab-ci-multi-runner "Docker mode" instance.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: soullivaneuh/docker-bash

before_script:
  - apk add --update bash curl
  - curl --silent --location https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.5.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - ./configure
  - docker-compose up -d
```

Note that [soullivaneuh/docker-bash](https://hub.docker.com/r/soullivaneuh/docker-bash/) image is just a docker image with bash installed.

The script fails on `docker-compose up -d` command:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
Using Docker executor with image soullivaneuh/docker-bash ...
Pulling docker image soullivaneuh/docker-bash:latest ...

Running on runner-1ee5079f-project-3-concurrent-1 via sd-59984...
Fetching changes...
Removing app/config/parameters.yml
Removing docker-compose.env
HEAD is now at 5c5e7ff remove docker service
From https://git.dummy.net/project/project
   5c5e7ff..45e643d  docker-ci  -> origin/docker-ci
Checking out 45e643dd as docker-ci...
Previous HEAD position was 5c5e7ff... remove docker service
HEAD is now at 45e643d... Remove docker info commands

$ apk add --update bash curl
fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.2/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 10 MiB in 28 packages
$ curl --silent --location https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.5.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ ./configure
$ docker-compose up -d
bash: line 30: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

I have absolutly no idea why this is failing.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I came across your question here 10 minutes after posting looking for the same answer. Amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `No such file or directory` is misleading. I've received that many times while trying to run dynamically linked binaries using alpine linux (which it appears you are using).

The problem (as I understand it) is that the binary was compiled and linked against glibc, but alpine uses musl, not glibc.

You could use `ldd /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` to tell you which libraries are missing (or run it with `strace` if all else fails).

To get it working, it might be easier to install from python source (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-using-pip), which is what the official compose image does (https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/Dockerfile.run).

Or you could use an image built on debian or some other distro that uses glibc.

Comment: I would like to use a debian based image, but it's the docker official image. I would like to not create mine. Will try your other solutions.

Comment: The ldd command gave me this: https://gist.github.com/Soullivaneuh/3cee5f17166c856a01fc I'm not sure of the result and what should I do.

Comment: And then the strace result: https://gist.github.com/Soullivaneuh/79b09f030965b2e41305 Not really verbose.

Comment: Finally the pip way is working. Now I have another issue but I thinks it would be for another question.